# How do I move database generated by IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine to my production server?

Tags: database, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I have created a website that is using IT Hit WebDAV Server. The MS SQL database was generated by the WebDAV wizard. How do I move it to another server?

Comment: @IT_Hit_WebDAV What is ithit tag?  I see 0 followers on that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IT Hit WebDAV Wizards for Visual Studio generate SQL file, called DB.sql, that creates tables and populate it with initial data. It is located in the root of your web project or in WebDAVServerImpl folder. In fact wizard was using this script to generate your initial database.

[image]

[image]